# gdb debugging what is the 8 byte gap for?

Tags: c, gdb, stack

I'm debugging a function to learn more about the structure of a stack in memory. I am using gdb on the Ubuntu OS x86. My function consists of the following:

```
function func(){
   long local1=0;
   printf("address of swap is %p\n",&local1);
}
```

In gdb I set a breakpoint inside the function and print out the frame values using `info frame`. I am able to get the address of the saved registers of ebp and eip which I presume holds the saved base pointer and return address respectively. I also print out the address of local1. So using these addresses I constructed the following stack:

```
bffff03c --> eip (stores the return address)
bffff038 --> ebp (saved base pointer)
bffff02c --> local1 address
```

Now I must be missing something because there is a 8 byte gap between ebp and local1. I assumed local1 data type is 4 bytes which leaves the address between `bffff030 -> bffff038` unaccounted for. Would really appreciate help with this one.

EDIT

here is the assembly code. the only anomaly i could think of is the `SUB` instruction following `mov esp,ebp`, though I'm not sure how it relates to the gap. [image]

Comment: Did you dump the assembly code for `func`?

Comment: I'm getting it 8 bytes down from `ebp` (no gap given that my sizeof(long)=8): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5fc8ee238e95988

Comment: printing sizeof(long) gives me 4

Comment: 16-byte stack alignment padding.

Comment: why 16 bytes? arent data types like long so called 'naturally aligned' and dont need padding?

Comment: @st4rgut A 16 byte alignment works better for SSE, etc. loads and stores.

Comment: I have thought long and hard but still dont understand. Where do the 8 bytes come from? the sum of memory in the stack is 12 bytes. So wouldn't only 4 bytes of padding be required? Why does compiler insert padding between ebp and local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 8 byte gap is because on x86 calling conventions require 16 byte stack alignment on entrance to a function, and a return pointer is only 8 bytes. So we get the 8 bytes of "wasted" space.

Comment: Can you share a link to a resource on this? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer "Links to external resources are encouraged..."